# To wait of a thread if it finished (Android)

Tags: android, multithreading, wait

I want to upload some files. I use the following source code in a for-loop:

```
Thread uploadThread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        uploadFile(sourcePath, destPath);
    }
};
uploadThread.start();
```

This works fine. Where and how can I check when the thread is finished ? I need a pause in the for-loop so long the thread is working. How can I do that ?

Comment: you could use AsyncTask.https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: You don't want to "pause" while it is uploading.  That could take a long time depending on size and network speed.  If you block waiting on this thread to finish, your UI will be unresponsive and the framework could kill your app due to ANR.

Comment: What happens with the Thread if the app goes to the background ? And what is the difference between AsyncTask and the source code above ?

Comment: @RolfWarnecke  Most likely the thread will be killed before it's complete.  Also Asynctask gives you more callbacks for when a thread has started and finished.  What you really want is an IntentService.

Comment: Use the LocalBroadastManager to broadcast from the IntentService that the download finished.

Answer (score 0):

You should use an Async Task. This is a kind of thread which allows you to get progress and ending informations.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {

  protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
     int count = urls.length;
     long totalSize = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
         totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
         publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
         // Escape early if cancel() is called
         if (isCancelled()) break;
     }
     return totalSize;
   }

 protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
     setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
 }

 protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
     showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
 }
```

}

*Source : Android Developer*

**onProgressUpdate** and **onPostExecute** are respectively called when the progress changes and when it is done.